# Video tag in svg foreignObject not rendered correctly on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

According to the SVG specificaition objects are to be rendered in the order of them being added to the SVG object. First SVG object is thus in the bottom and then on top of that and so on.

In my example below the video is the first object and should be rendered behind the circle but on Chrome it still appears on top.

I assume there is a bug in Chrome. Is there a workaround?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="200">
  <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">
    <video autoplay="" loop="" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/flower.webm" type="video/webm">      
    </video>
 </foreignObject> 
 <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="100" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Here's a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ErlingM/05cf7nod/48/

Comment: You should report Chrome bugs to Google's Chrome bugtracker.

Comment: Thanks. I've done that now.